# is Adobe AIR's openWithDefaultApplication() not available in the AJAX SDK?

Tags: air

The only documentation of Adobe AIR's `openWithDefaultApplication()` function I can find is a tutorial for it in the Flex SDK. Is Flex required to use this function?

Calling it via JavaScript results in:

```
TypeError: Value undefined does not allow function calls.
```

The code I'm using:

```
var poster = air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('posters/CR-1/CR-1.pps');
air.trace(poster); // [object File]
poster.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

Answer (score 1):

The application file is likely set to....
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5">

You must change it to

<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.0">

for the 2.0 + functionality to work....